# Find the Surface Area of the portion of cylinder $x^2 + y^2 =4y$ lying inside the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 16$

Tags: calculus, integration

Here we're asked to find S.A. of cylinder lying inside sphere which comes out to be $64$.

I know the regular method of finding S.A. of same sphere inside cylinder which comes out to be  $32(\pi-2)$.  (which is far away from $64$, and I do not know any other way of solving it).

Kindly explain the procedure of solving using double Integral. Thank you.

Comment: What is the regular method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$C_1: x^2+y^2+z^2 = 16$$

$$C_2: x^2+y^2 = 4y$$

[image]
Projecting the surface on the $yz - $plane, we can get the surface area as,

$$S = 2\int\int_R\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\bigg)^2+1} \ dydz$$

(Due to symmetry)

where $R$ is the region obtained by eliminating $x^2$ from $C_1$ and $C_2$

So,

> $$z^2+4y = 16$$

The surface is

> $$x^2+y^2 = 4y$$

Now, $$1) \ \ \ 2x\frac{\partial x }{\partial y} + 2y = 4 \implies \frac{\partial x}{\partial y } = \frac{4-2y}{2x} = \frac{2-y}{x}$$

$$2) \ \ \ 2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = 0 \implies \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = 0$$

$$\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\bigg)^2+1 = \bigg(\frac{2-y}{x}\bigg)^2+ 0 +1 = \frac{(2-y)^2 + x^2}{x^2} = \frac{4 - 4y + y^2 + x^2}{x^2} = \frac{4- 0}{x^2} = \frac{4}{x^2}$$

So, $$\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\bigg)^2+1} = \frac{2}{x} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{4y-y^2}} \text{, from } C_2$$

Also, $$z^2+4y = 16 \implies z = \pm\sqrt{16-4y}$$

$$S = 2\int\int_R \frac{2}{\sqrt{4y-y^2}} dydz =2\int^4_0\int^{\sqrt{16-4y}}_{-\sqrt{16-4y}} \frac{2}{\sqrt{4y-y^2}} dydz $$

$$S = 4 \int^4_0 \bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{4y-y^2}}(\sqrt{16-4y} + \sqrt{16-4y})\bigg]dy =8 \int^4_0\bigg[\frac{\sqrt{16-4y}}{\sqrt{4y-y^2}}\bigg]dy$$

$$S =8\int^4_0\bigg[\frac{\sqrt{4(4-y)4y}}{\sqrt{y(4-y)}}\bigg]dy  $$

$$S = 8\int^4_0 \frac{2}{\sqrt y }dy = 16[2 \sqrt y ]^4_0  = 32\cdot 2 = 64$$

> $$S = 64$$

Comment: Can you help me to understand, on which plane do we need to see the projection? Most of the questions I encountered are solved by using the xy plane for projection. Can't we do that here?

Comment: On the $yz$ plane as shown in the first diagram.

Comment: In that case the surface of the sphere will be projected on the $xy$ plane and on integrating it gives $\color{blue}{32(\pi-2)}$ as you found. In order to find the cylinder's area, we have to project it on the $\color{green}{yz}$ plane.

Comment: Okay, and what if I try using $xz$ plane for solving? Would I still reach where I want to?

Comment: We can do if the equation were $\color{blue}{x^2+y^2 = 4x}$ where the equation can be written as $(x-2)^2 + y^2 = 4$ but here we have $\color{blue}{x^2+y^2 = 4x 
 \implies x^2+(y-2)^2 = 4}$. So we have  to project in the $yz$ plane, so that we get the whole projection of one side of the cylinder of radius $2$

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm understanding a bit. Just one more query.  What if the equation was $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ ? Which plane would you prefer then?

Comment: In that case both $xz$ and $yz$ will work, but in the last step the limits will be from $-2 \to 2$ for both $x$ and $y$ (according to the case you consider)

Comment: And the z limits would be $± \sqrt{12}$ ?

Comment: Yes you got it....

Comment: Yaayyyy....... :D

Answer (score 1):

Since the cylinder has area element $\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}z$, we can integrate the arclength $s(z)=2\theta(z)$ of the intersection of the region with the circle at constant $z$ to get the surface area of the region.

At constant $z\in[-4,4]$, the intersection of $x^2+y^2\leq 16-z^2$ and $x^2+y^2-4y=0$ is an arc of angle $\theta(z)=2(\pi-\arccos(1-\frac18z^2))$.  Integrating from $z=-4$ to $4$ gives the surface area
$$
A=\int_{-4}^4 4(\pi-\arccos(1-\tfrac18z^2))\,\mathrm{d}z=64.
$$

Comment: Sry, I don't think I understand your solution. I'm trying to solve such questions using double Integral. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Bishamon, you should specify clealry what kind of method you are looking for. Otherwise, people who are willing to help, end up providing all kinds of answers.

Comment: @Dunkel acknowledged

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let radius of sphere be $a=4$. The situation gives rise to
[Viviani's Window.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VivianisCurve.html)

Development of the required area comprises two halves of a Sine curve area which is $\dfrac{2}{\pi}$ fraction of enclosing rectangle, can be easily calculated separately.

In the present case

$$ A= \frac{2}{\pi}.(2\pi a) (2a)= 4a^2 = 64. $$

Hope the recognition is interesting.. :) .. Upto you to down-vote.

Comment: Well I'm not yet familiar with Viviani's window, and hence not in a position to down-vote your answer too. Cheers! ^_^

Comment: Plus why do I feel like your A comes out to be $8a^2$ , which will result to 128 ?

Answer (score 0):

Let shift the origin of the coordinates to the point $(0,2,0)$ so that the equation of the sphere and cylinder are
$$
x^2+(y+2)^2+z^2=16\text{ and } x^2+y^2=4,\tag1 
$$
respectively.

For $z$ coordinate of the intersection curve one obtains from (1) the equation:
$$z^2=8-4y,$$
or, in cylindrical coordinates (with $R=2$ being the radius of the cylinder) $x=2\cos\phi, y=2\sin\phi$:
$$
z=\pm\sqrt{8-8\cos\phi}=\pm 4\sin\frac\phi2,
$$
so that an element of the cylindrical surface area is $h\cdot Rd\phi=(2|z|)(2d\phi)=4|z|d\phi$ and for the whole area one obtains:
$$
A=\int_{0}^{2\pi} 4|z|d\phi=16\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\frac{\phi}2d\phi=64.
$$